# Using multiple datasource on a Reporting Services report?

Tags: reporting-services, report, database-connection, datasource, error-reporting

I have a report that contains two datasets. Each dataset is connected to two different datasources. The databases are on the same server.

I can run the report without problems in the preview of Visual Studio 2008 and extract the data from the two datasets without problem.

But I get an error when I try to run the report from the system when you post.

It generates the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error has occurred during report processing.
---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing.
---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.DataSetExecutionException: The execution failed for the shared data set 'DATASET_NAME'.
---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset ''.
---> System.Exception: For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
Server stack trace:
  en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
  en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:
  en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  en ReportServices.ReportExecutionServiceReference.ReportExecutionServiceSoap.Render(RenderRequest request)
  en ReportServices.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be at a number of places.

According to the error, the report is using a shared data set, called `DATASET_NAME` and that dataset is having a problem.

Check the following:
   - Verify that the dataset is set to use a valid data source.
   - Check the data source credentials.
   - Try executing the report in BIDS (Visual Studio) with the same credentials as used in the  data source on the server.
   - Create a test report that uses only this one dataset, and returns the data as a simple table.

Comment: Will update the dataset and the report on the server.
Thank you very much the problem has been solved.